# How do I assert an HTML maxlength of a function is equal to what I need it to be

Tags: python, selenium, unit-testing, pycharm, webdriver

I am trying to write a code that will get the maxlength value from the HTML I am testing and assert that the maxlength of the first name input section is equal to 40. I wrote a unittest for it but it passes no matter what value I enter. I want it to only pass if the maxlength value in the HTML is equal to 40.

This is currently what I have:

```
def test_SPmax(self):
    time.sleep(3)
    first_name = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
        '/html/body/div[4]/div[1]/section/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/section/div/section/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/fieldset/div/div[2]/input').get_attribute('maxlength')
    if len(first_name) == 40:
        assert True
```

Comment: Can you share the HTML source?

Comment: <input class="firstName compoundBorderBottom form-element__row input" maxlength="40" type="text" aria-describedby="" placeholder="First Name" id="1601:0" data-aura-rendered-by="1605:0" data-interactive-lib-uid="3">

Answer (score 0):

why are you using `len()` ?

`.get_attribute` would return a `str`

```
expected_vlaue = "40"
if first_name == '40':
   print('yes max length is 40')
   assert first_name in expected_vlaue
   print('assert verified')
else:
   print('No')
```

**Update 1 :**

```
expected_vlaue = "40"
first_name = first_name = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
        '/html/body/div[4]/div[1]/section/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/section/div/section/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/fieldset/div/div[2]/input').get_attribute('maxlength')
if first_name == '40':
   print('yes max length is 40')
   try:
       assert first_name in expected_vlaue
       print('Assertion worked perfectly')
   except:
       print("Assertion must have failed")
else:
   print('looks like max length is not 40')
   try:
       assert first_name in expected_vlaue
   except:
       print("Assertion must have failed")
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. But how do I get the test to fail if first_name is not equal to the expected value? When I use your code and change the value of the expected_value and first name I want it to fail if the maxlength is not equal to it.

Comment: @Jzaza24 : Can you try out the updated code above ? it has all the checks that you need.

Comment: I tried the updated code however it would return 'looks like max length is not 40' and 'assertion must have failed' even when the max length was equal to 40. I tried tweaking your original code to use "else: assert false" to see if that would fail the test if the value was not 40 but I kept getting an AssertionError.